# Update or reinstall dd-wrt firmware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

[image]Good day,

I have a Linksys E3000 router. I had previously installed DD-WRT firmware (or at least i thought i did) on it a few months ago but my web interface never changed. The only change i noticed is that the favicon on the home page of the router's web interface changed to DD-WRT (the other pages didn't change). However, the router still functions properly. 
I didn't know at the time that my interface needed to change after installation so i thought my installation was correct.

Now i want to use some DD-WRT functionalities (like monitoring device bandwidth usage) and i'm not sure if i need to update the firmware or do a fresh firmware installation. I really can't afford to brick my router or cause it any harm. Please what do i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that you're actually running DD-WRT (e.g. a screenshot)? FWIW you can backup your current config (provided you're actually running DD-WRT) from `Administration - Backup`.

Comment: There's a back up option as shown in the screen shot. But i still have the cisco interface. That's why i am not sure if dd-wrt is running or not.

Comment: That's certainly not DD-WRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the firmware version, if you're running DD-WRT it will tell you.

From what you've said so far it sounds like you only flashed your router once. You need at least two flashes for an e3000 so it's suffice to say you did it wrong. For your router you must flash it with a trailed build first, then after that you flash it again with the build of your choice.

Make sure you're flashing the right build.

Read over this wiki http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E3000 and then, read over it again.

Follow every step to the letter and you'll be fine.

Comment: Okay thanks. So this means i would follow the instructions for installing fresh dd-wrt firmware in the peacock announcement right?

Comment: @ss_millionaire - Just follow the instructions

Comment: @ss_millionaire - Haha yep, I know the instructions are complicated but you need to read though it to determine if your router needs the k24 build or the k26. Once you figure that out it's smooth sailing. Usually they'll have a model number you can go off to determine whether your router's ram is nv60 or nv64. You may even be able to see how much NVRAM you have using your current setup.

Comment: @Ramhound you obviously didn't understand my question. But rastaBob answered me already.

Comment: @ss_millionaire - I have the same router.  I understood your question.  I was just confirming you should follow the instructions.